# How can you have a UILabel change text every second from each item in an NSArray Then rotate through again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I would like to have my UILabel change text every second (fading in and out when changed) for each item in my array, then when at the end go through it again. I have tried:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    NSArray *arrayOfText = @[@"Test1",@"Test2",@"Test3",@"Test4"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfText count]; i++) {

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];

        self.changingTextLabel.text = [arrayOfText objectAtIndex:i];

    }


}
```

This would load the ViewController, and after about 8 seconds change the text to the last item in the array.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I have looked for a solution over the past few days and nothing has worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never sleep on the main queue. It blocks your app's user interface.

You have a few options but using an `NSTimer` is probably the easiest.

Add a couple of instance variables to your class:

```
@implementation WhateverViewController {
    NSTimer *_labelTimer;
    NSInteger labelIndex = 0;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    NSArray *arrayOfText = @[@"Test1",@"Test2",@"Test3",@"Test4"];

    // Setup a timer to run every 2 seconds and update the label
    // Increment the labelIndex so the next label is shown next time
    _labelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer *timer) {
        self.changingTextLabel.text = arrayOfText[labelIndex];
        labelIndex = (labelIndex + 1) % arrayOfText.count;
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // Stop the timer when we leave
    [_labelTimer invalidate];
    _labelTimer = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Make sure it is stopped
    [_labelTimer invalidate];
}
```